# Mulitple choice question in Exercise package

Tags: exercises

I am creating an assignment for students that would contain some several chapters with theory, exercise and solution. I want to create multiple choice questions using exercise package of latex. I believe this package does not directly support MCQs. I have come across a few pieces of the code that I have combined.

My aim is to create MCQs with one or more than one correct answers such that all answers along with explanations and analysis should appear at the end of the chapter.

If someone suggest other packages/methods, it would be fine too.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsbook}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[cmintegrals, cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}% you must load it before the exercise package
\usepackage[answerdelayed]{exercise}
\usepackage{environ}

\newlength{\choiceslen}
\newif\ifshowcorrect
\newcounter{choices}
\newcommand{\choicefinal}[1]{%
\ifnum\value{choices}>0 \hfill\fi\egroup
\hspace{0pt}%
\hbox to\choiceslen
\bgroup
\stepcounter{choices}%
\ifcase#1\relax
(\Alph{choices})%
\else
\ifshowcorrect
\expandafter\bfseries
\fi
{(\Alph{choices})}%
\fi\space
}
\newcommand{\choicetemp}[1]{%
\stepcounter{choices}%
\space(\Alph{choices})\cr
}

\NewEnviron{choices}{%
\setcounter{choices}{0}%
\let\choice\choicetemp
\shorthandchoice% <---------- Add \choice shorthand
\settowidth{\choiceslen}{\vbox{\halign{##\hfil\cr\BODY\crcr}}}
\ifdim\choiceslen>.5\textwidth
\setlength{\choiceslen}{\textwidth}%
\else
\ifdim\choiceslen>.25\textwidth
\setlength{\choiceslen}{.5\textwidth}%
\else
\setlength{\choiceslen}{.25\textwidth}%
\fi
\fi
\let\choice\choicefinal
\shorthandchoice% <---------- Add \choice shorthand
\setcounter{choices}{0}%

\begin{flushleft}
\bgroup\BODY\hfill\egroup
\end{flushleft}
}

\newcommand{\shorthandchoice}{%
\let\oldchoice\choice
\renewcommand{\choice}{\oldchoice{0}}
\def\correctchoice{\oldchoice{1}}
}
\parindent 0pt
\linespread{1.1}

\begin{document}
\begin{Exercise}[label={mylabel}]
What is the value of 2+5? Which fruit do you like?(To see the answer click here: \refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel})
\showcorrecttrue
\begin{choices}
\correctchoice apple
\choice banana
\correctchoice orange
\choice pear
\end{choices}
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
7 
\end{Answer}

\begin{ExerciseList}
\Exercise What is the value of $\pi$  \showcorrecttrue
\begin{choices}
\correctchoice apple
\choice banana
\correctchoice orange
\choice pear
\end{choices}
\Answer Approximate value is 22/7.
\Exercise What is the value of $e$
\Answer Approximate value is 2.71...
\end{ExerciseList}
\clearpage
\begin{center}
\textbf{\textit{    Answers.}}
\end{center}
\newpage % I've added a new page only to clearly show the hyperlink. Of course, you don't need it in your document.
\shipoutAnswer
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does the provided answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure this is what you want to achieve, but you could use `tasks` package.

*Updated version of the answer*

Since version v1.0 of the `tasks` (2019/10/04) the option `counter-format` is deprecated, now it is possible to use `label` like in `enumitem`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsbook}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[cmintegrals, cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}% you must load it before the exercise package
\usepackage[answerdelayed, lastexercise]{exercise}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{
    label = {(\Alph*)},
    label-width=1.4em
    }

\begin{document}
\chapter{Exercises}
\begin{Exercise}[label={mylabel}]
What is the value of 2+5? (To see the answer click here: \refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel})
\begin{tasks}(4)
\task 2
\task 5
\task\label{correctchoice}7
\task 3
\end{tasks}
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
\ref{correctchoice} 7
\end{Answer}
\begin{Exercise}[label={mysecondlabel}]
Which fruit do you like? (To see the answer click here: \refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel})
\begin{tasks}(4)
\task\label{apple}apple
\task banana
\task\label{orange}orange
\task pear
\end{tasks}
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
\ref{apple} apple or \ref{orange} orange 
\end{Answer}
\begin{Exercise}[label={mythirdlabel}]
What is the value of $\pi$? (To see the answer click here: \refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel})
\begin{tasks}(4)
\task 2.15
\task 1.31
\task 4.3
\task\label{correct}3.14
\end{tasks}
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
\ref{correct} 3.14
\end{Answer}
\chapter{Answers}
\shipoutAnswer
\end{document}
```

*Old version of the answer*

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{amsbook}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage[cmintegrals, cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{hyperref}% you must load it before the exercise package
\usepackage[answerdelayed, lastexercise]{exercise}
\usepackage{tasks}
\settasks{
    counter-format = {(tsk[A])},
    label-width=1.4em
    }

\begin{document}
\chapter{Exercises}
\begin{Exercise}[label={mylabel}]
What is the value of 2+5? (To see the answer click here: \refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel})
\begin{tasks}(4)
\task 2
\task 5
\task\label{correctchoice}7
\task 3
\end{tasks}
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
\ref{correctchoice} 7
\end{Answer}
\begin{Exercise}[label={mysecondlabel}]
Which fruit do you like? (To see the answer click here: \refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel})
\begin{tasks}(4)
\task\label{apple}apple
\task banana
\task\label{orange}orange
\task pear
\end{tasks}
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
\ref{apple} apple or \ref{orange} orange 
\end{Answer}
\begin{Exercise}[label={mythirdlabel}]
What is the value of $\pi$? (To see the answer click here: \refAnswer{\ExerciseLabel})
\begin{tasks}(4)
\task 2.15
\task 1.31
\task 4.3
\task\label{correct}3.14
\end{tasks}
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}[ref=\ExerciseLabel]
\ref{correct} 3.14
\end{Answer}
\chapter{Answers}
\shipoutAnswer
\end{document}
```

In both cases, the output is:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks CarLaTeX, I think that should work. I shall check this for options that would fill half of the textwidth or so. Thank you.

Comment: CarLaTeX Hi, Is there a possibility to auto-label exercise?

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I thought something like this might be feasible. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/285211/auto-generating-labels-for-theorems

Comment: Per the `tasks` v1.3a Manual, the option `counter-format` has been deprecated; see pp. 8–11.

Comment: @FrenzyLi I updated my answer, thank you.